# What is the origin of this set_Visible exception during shutdown of winforms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I have wrapped the Application.Run method in try/catch

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
   try {
       MyClient client = new MyClient();
       client.Run(args);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { log.Error("Failed to start client",ex); }
}
```

Where MyClient is just:

```
class MyClient : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
```

and during every shutdown I get this exception

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'MainView'.
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
  at MyProgram.Main(String[] args) in C:\svn\trunk\MyProgram\client\MyProgram\Program.cs:line 54
```

If I set a breakpoint in the debugger in the catch block my callstack is all empty except for the `client.Run(..)`.

As far as I can understand the stacktrace the problem is somewhere some code is doing `MainView.Visible = ....` but I can find anything in my code that resembles this.

How can I figure out the origin of the exception?

The MainView is created like this inside `MyClient`:

```
protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
{
   string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
   try {
        MainView mainView = new MainView(args);
        this.MainForm = mainView;
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(mainView);
   }catch(Exception ex){ log.Warn("Exception in OnCreateMainForm",ex); }
}
```

And closing like this:

```
public void OnKilled()
{
   log.Debug("OnKilled. Exiting");
   Application.Exit();
}
```

`MainView` is defined like:

```
public partial class MainView : Form
{
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.MainView_FormClosing);
    }
    private void MainView_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        log.DebugFormat("'MainView_FormClosing': {0}",e.CloseReason);
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown || e.CloseReason == CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall)
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
            Application.Exit();
        }
}
```

Comment: You have 'wrapped Application.Run'???  What is the context of this code?  Where is the Main() method in the stack trace?

Comment: wrapped as in `try { Application.Run... }catch...`. There is no main method in the stacktrace. That is the baffling part.

Comment: What is MainView?  Is it a form?  It may be calling MainView.Show() somewhere.  It seems likely that at some point, the code is attempting to show a form that has already been disposed.  If the form was first shown using the Show method, then it is automatically disposed when its Close method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!

It turns out that `Application.Run` in OnCreateMainForm is the big No-No. `WindowsFormsApplicationBase` takes over the ApplicationRun when `OnCreateMainForm` returns so in my case I only returned from `OnCreateMainForm` when MainForm already were disposed hence the exception :(

```
 protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
 {
     string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
     try {
           MainView mainView = new MainView(args);
           this.MainForm = mainView;
           Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     }...
 }
```

Comment: You also don't need the `OnKilled` thing. The purpose of calling `Application.Exit` is to exit from a message loop. If `OnKilled` is being called, you are about to get out of the message loop anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the code that you use in order to create the main window, and the code that you use in order to close it?

Without seeing more code, I would guess that somewhere in your code you are calling `Dispose` on the windows, instead of using `Close`. But that's just a guess.

By the way, why are you using `WindowsFormsApplicationBase` if this is a C# program?

Comment: Can you post the code that creates the window and the code that shuts down the application?

Comment: Uses the WindowsFormsApplicationBase to take advantage of IsSingleInstance mechanics